# How to feature-detect event.which in mousemove listeners?

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection

Chrome seems to have `event.which === 1` in a `mousemove` listener if the left mouse button is currently depressed at the time of the move event.

But Firefox doesn't; it only sets `event.which` in `mousedown` and `mouseup`. I don't know about other browsers.

Can anyone think of a good way to feature-detect this behaviour?

Note: I know you can hack it using mousedown and mouseup listeners to update a `mouseIsPressed` variable, but this isn't a good hack in my situation (a drag interaction inside an iframed window, ie no way to catch the mouseup if it happens outside the iframe), so I want to use the native `event.which` where available.

Answer (score 2):

DOM Level 3 [defines `MouseEvent#buttons`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#widl-MouseEvent-buttons), which [Firefox supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.buttons). From [the MDN article on `mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove):

> The buttons being pressed when the mouse event was fired: Left button=1, Right button=2, Middle (wheel) button=4, 4th button (typically, "Browser Back" button)=8, 5th button (typically, "Browser Forward" button)=16. If two or more buttons are pressed, returns the logical sum of the values. E.g., if Left button and Right button are pressed, returns 3 (=1 | 2).

Comment: oh ok that's good. what about other browsers though? is there a way to test any browser to see if it supports this spec? specifically event.which on mousemove? the problem is I need to know ahead of time whether it's supported, as the answer to this will affect what I do in the mousedown to set up the drag interaction.

Comment: @callum: You can check for standard support using `document.createEvent && 'buttons' in document.createEvent('MouseEvent')`. `which` isn’t standard, though, and you’ll just have to test it yourself and see whether its coverage is acceptable for you.